# Getting scipy's rv_discrete to work with floating point values?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to define my own discrete distribution. The code I have works for integer values but not for decimal values. For example, this works:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import rv_discrete
>>> probabilities = [0.2, 0.5, 0.3]
>>> values = [1, 2, 3]
>>> distrib = rv_discrete(values=(values, probabilities))
>>> print distrib.rvs(size=10)
[1 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 1 3]
```

But if I use decimal values, it doesn't work:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import rv_discrete
>>> probabilities = [0.2, 0.5, 0.3]
>>> values = [.1, .2, .3]
>>> distrib = rv_discrete(values=(values, probabilities))
>>> print distrib.rvs(size=10)
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [`stats.rv_discrete`'s doc string](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.html):

> values : tuple of two array_like, optional
>           `(xk, pk)` where `xk` are **integers** with non-zero
>           probabilities `pk`  with `sum(pk) = 1`.

(my emphasis). So the discrete distributions created by `rv_discrete` must use integer values. However, it is not hard to map those integer values to floats by using the rvs values as integer indices into `values`:

```
In [4]: values = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])

In [5]: idx = distrib.rvs(size=10); idx
Out[5]: array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1])

In [6]: values[idx]
Out[6]: array([ 0.2,  0.2,  0.1,  0.1,  0.2,  0.2,  0.1,  0.3,  0.2,  0.2])
```

---

Thus you could use:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
np.random.seed(2016)
probabilities = np.array([0.2, 0.5, 0.3])
values = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
distrib = stats.rv_discrete(values=(range(len(probabilities)), probabilities))
idx = distrib.rvs(size=10)
result = values[idx]
print(result)
# [ 0.3  0.3  0.3  0.3  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.3  0.3  0.2]
```

Comment: This should make its way to the scipy docs. Interested in sending a pull request, @unutbu? (see also https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3758)

Comment: @ev-br: I think the scipy docs would become extraordinarily large if it did not presume
a facility with numpy. So I don't see how this could be inserted there with
concision. However, you are welcome to use any part of what I've written that
you'd like to include there.

Comment: but i want to use it in RandomizedSearchCV